# How can i find which DIrectX version install on my system through code

Tags: c#, .net, directx

How can i find the current install version of directx on my system using code(C#).

Answer (score 0):

On xp you can check `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX"` registry for DirectX version

Comment: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX" showing me 4.09.00.0094 while i have 9.0C install on my machine, although i also want that my could should work on vista as well.

Comment: InstalledVersion key is 9, I don't know how you can get letter C, you have installed 9c(4.09.00.0094), isn't it? unfortunately  it will not work on vista...

Answer (score 0):

I realize that it's slightly off topic...

You might want to look into using SlimDX as a managed DirectX wrapper instead of Managed DirectX, since Microsoft has dropped support for 64-bit DirectX in Managed DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

What about dynamically requesting different versions of DirectX objects through COM via the CoCreateInstance call?  Check for fail conditions which would indicate a version is not available.  Check one-by-one with the latest version until you get an object successfully.